# execve error when calling execve( man, args, env )

Tags: c, linux

I'm having trouble with this `execve` command.  I can use it to run most other commands just fine in my program, but if I try to do like `man ls` or something I get this error.

```
man: can't execute pager: No such file or directory
man: command exited with status 255: LESS=-ix8RmPm Manual page ls(1) ?ltline     %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$PM Manual page   ls(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$ MAN_PN=ls(1) pager -s
```

Here is how I'm calling it:

```
execve( cmdPath, args, env );
```

where `cmdPath` is the path(in this case `/usr/bin/man`)
`args` is a `char*` where `args[0] = man`, `args[1] = ls`
`env` is my `env*[]` passed from main.

Any help would be much appreciated.  I'm dying here.

Comment: Can you run `man ls` correctly from the same shell that you use to start your program?

Comment: Could you try with `args[0] = ls`

Comment: found the error. My env[15] (the PATH= stuff) is different than my getenv("PATH") for some reason.  If I hard code in the string of all my paths everything works perfectly.  Just wondering why now my int main( int argc, char *argv[], char *env[] ) env is different than my unix env.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Null terminate the arguments you pass to execve. Something like

```
char *args[3];
// other args..
args[2] = (char*) 0;
```

It is undefined behavior otherwise which is probably why it has worked sometimes in the past and this time you got unlucky.

This works:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *env[])
{
    char *args[3];

    args[0] = "man";
    args[1] = "ls";
    args[2] = (char*) 0;

    execve("/usr/bin/man", args, env);
}
```

Comment: well this works only if I set my env[0] = NULL.  - and even then it gives me a warning that the terminal is not behaving corectly before I can see the man page.  I did notice however that my env[] is not the same as if I just type env at the prompt So if I look at my PATH variable normally I have like 8 different paths.  But in my c program if I print the env variables there is only one PATH.

Comment: oh boy.  I found the error.  I just went in and hard coded env[15] to be the string "PATH=/usr/bin:........" all the things that getenv("PATH") gives me and everything works perfectly.  But why is my env[15] different from my getenv("PATH") to start with?  I am so confused.